# Button intent in TabFragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,null);


    }}
```

This is the whole code for fragment tab 1.. 
I have a program with two TabFragments , and I want to declare an image button and button intent in fragment tab 1 and 2,  but I can't do it , and the findviewbyid did not work..

What can I do to declare buttons intent ??

Comment: Just add the needed views to your XML resource file which seems to be `res/layout/home.xml`.

Comment: I have a textview and button and image button , card viewin my xml file , but i cant defined them in home java file to make intent to anther page?

Comment: I think I don't understand what's your problem. You have your views in XML, they get inflated in `onCreateView` method. Are you looking to write a method to handle your button clicks?

Comment: Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);  if i write this command (findViewByid) not work and the color of it is red,

Comment: yes i want method to handle my button click

Comment: can i contact with you by email , because i cant upload image here

Answer (score 0):

To handle button clicks (and view clicks in general) [`View.OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) interface is used. All you have to do is override its `onClick` method and assign it to a view by calling [`setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).

You can also find a thorough tutorial [here](http://www.androiddevresources.com/guides/tutorial-how-to-implement-an-onclicklistener/).

**UPD:** Your method should look like this:

```
public View onCreateView(.....) {

    // assign inflated view to a variable
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout_services, null);

    // set your listener
    v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(.....);

    // return the view in the end
    return v;
}
```

The problem is that you're instantly returning the inflated view and the code below wouldn't run at all, this is why there's that error.

**UPD2:** Now the problem is that `startActivity` method is receiving `Context` as a first parameter, so you should pass your activity there by calling `getActivity()` (instead of passing `Services.this`). You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

**UPD3:** You don't seem to understand what your code does. Your `findViewById` call is useless because it's not getting assigned to a variable, and your `setOnClickListener` is getting applied to the entire fragment view. Here's what that part should look like:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Admin.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I'd recommend to learn how all those methods work (at least have a look at the reference, to begin with: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))) before trying to actually write an application. Good luck with it.

Comment: can you see this image , and tell me where is the error

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/xc2lir.png           ,         http://i59.tinypic.com/2f0g3tu.png          ,

Comment: this two images for Fragment tab where i define the tabs

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/2zr18ap.png      Now i have this error how can i deal with it ?

Comment: Do you have any more questions?

Comment: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.services, null);



        // set your listener
        v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Admin.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

Comment: Any more questions? Did I help you solving the problem?